# wp-admin não carrega os scripts

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

O cliente instalou SSL em seu site e após isso algumas coisas não funcionaram mais, tais como imagens, scripts, css. Então instalei o plugin SSL Insecure Content e corrigiu. Porém o wp-admin continua com esse erro.

Sei que esse erro se dá pois é uma requisição http para um servidor https, mas não sei como resolver.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Pode mostrar qual o erro? Uma saída no console, o log do wp ou coisa do tipo, só pra ser mais específico?

Comment: Segue link da imagem:
https://www.jhsf.com.br/console.jpg

Comment: Em algum momento vc trocou o link do site e as demais referências para apontar para o endereço `https`?

Comment: Mas existem alguns scripts que são oriundos de plugins, entao se eu editar manualmente ao atualizar a versao do mesmo irá retornar o erro.
Outra, são varios links, não tem como fazer isso de forma automatica?

Comment: A maneira q uso pra fazer uma migração / atualização do tipo é pegar o dump do banco e buscar todas as ocorrências do link antigo e substituir pelo endereço correto. Pois mesmo depois de vc alterar o endereço principal no painel administrativo e outros lugares no código, "sempre" fica alguma referência em banco. Então geralmente resolvo por lá.